# fetching image information in cloudfoundry registry of dockerimage

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

I have cloudfoundry registry, I have pushed alpine:3.6 docker image into cloudfoundry.
when I directly invoke

> > docker inspect alpine:3.6
> > this will give me all the image information. Is there any api in cf which will give me all the application image details ?
> > Actually I want to fetch config, RootFs all this information from cloudfoundry using cloudfoundry api.

Comment: Not sure I follow. What do you mean by a "cloudfoundry registry"? What commands are you running? What output do you see? What is missing, what specifically are you trying to find? Nee more details here. Thanks

Comment: There is platform called https://cloudfoundry.org/ in which we can push our  docker images to run as applications. For example, if I have alpine:3.6 image in my Docker Hub, I can use  " cf push cf-sample-app --docker-image alpine:3.6"   This will push alpine:3.6 as container.  Now if we docker inspect alpine:3.6 this will give us all the details. Similarly is there any API or Command in cf client to fetch such kind of information ? I am mostly interested in RootFs.Layers information. Let me know If I want to give some more details.

Comment: When you push a docker image to CF, there is only the docker image. The platform does not contribute a rootfs, like it does with buildpack generated applications. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/docker.html. Thus you can inspect your images using any tool you like to extract information about them.

Comment: To get information about your application on CF, you can run `cf app <name>`, or use `cf curl` to make requests to the API directly. Use the v3 API. Interesting resources to look at would be apps, packages, and droplets. See http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.112.0/index.html#resources

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, I will look into the provided links.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually we want Docker Image >> Root Fs >> layerids. This we cannot fetch if the same docker image push to cloudfoundry registry. Searching for any API which will help us to fetch image/rootfs/layerids. Otherwise we will try with different approach.